# Using STL dynamically instead of statically in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, stl

I was reading an article about reducing your win32 PE size :
http://www.catch22.net/tuts/reducing-executable-size

I am currently working on a project which one of its characteristics is a very small PE size.

I asked myself - **is STL (That is - the standard templates library) usable dynamically instead of statically?**

I guess that because it uses templates which are compile-time generated it can be a bit of a problem.

so - is it possible?

Comment: "no". oh wait must have fitteen crachaters ... blah

Comment: That tutorial is 12 years old and worries that we will have to buy larger hard drives. We already have bigger **and** cheaper hard drives. Don't worry!

Comment: If you want the absolute smallest PE size for your application/DLL, it is doable using WIN32 API's for *almost* everything. For example, using standard template containers requires memory mgmt, and we are conveniently given override capability via allocator provision. Writing a win32 heap-based allocator isn't rocket science. Properly setup, you can get a *remarkably* small PE footprint, but the cost in managing it can be encompassing, and eventually can be damn difficult, but not impossible. I don't know what restrictions you're under, but seriously think about whether you *really* need this.

Comment: Why don't you code the whole thing in assembly?

Comment: @BoPersson: The entire world is not yet on DSL or cable internet though, unfortunately. Saving 100 KB can mean a lot in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible. MSVC++ has a DLL version of its standard libraries which contains e.g. `std::string` You can use the same technique to add additional DLLs with your instantiations.